# Vertical table gaps in Chrome browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-table

I'm hoping someone can help me with this baffling problem.

I created a landing page using photoshop's slice tool to piece together a large image with some CSS styles added in the source code.  The page renders perfectly on IE (versions 7 through 9) and on Firefox.  But on the Chrome browser, it has several vertical gaps between images -- any suggestions to resolve this would be GREATLY appreciated!

I've narrowed down the problem to the following line of code that is causing the problem...

```
<td colspan="5" rowspan="2" background="images/index_28.jpg" width="296" height="32">
  <input type="text" name="Email" size="45" id="entry" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

I had some input text fields that were sized too long and it was pushing the table boundaries beyond the actual size of the background image, thus causing the "vertical gaps".  Shortening the input text field solved the problem.

Hope this answer helps someone else who encounters the same problem!